# Thymeleaf +Spring Boot can't find files (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, filenotfoundexception

This is a bit of a silly and frustrating one:
The @Configuration is taken from a tutorial website or forum and in it a

```
ServletContextTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver
```

is created using the ServletContext provided by spring boot.
When requested, a FileNotFoundException is thrown, despite the file being in the configured resources folder.
How do I get it to find the file / load it from the resources?

Answer (score 2):

For thymeleaf to resolve the classpath resources, you need to configure a **`ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`**. (You were using a `ServletContextTemplateResolver`)

Also check that setPrefix is set to the correct folder, eg. "/thymeleaf/" if your documents are in resources/thymeleaf/ and that setSuffix is set to ".html" (or whatever your preferred file suffix is)

To also serve static content, you can extend `WebMvcConfigurer` and override `addResourceHandlers`, to then do e.g.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```

assuming a static folder in your resources.

(Spring controllers take precedence here)